# Why am I getting a seg fault (multidimensional arrays C)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int height = 4, width = 6;
  int **map;
  map = (int **)(malloc(height * sizeof(int*)));
  for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    map[i] = (int *)(malloc(width * sizeof(int)));
  }
  fill_map(&map, height, width);
}

void fill_map(int ***map, int height, int width) {
  int i, k, character;
  for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    k = 0;
    while((character = getchar()) != '\n') {
        *map[i][k] = character;
        k++;
    }
  }
}
```

I get a segfault in fill_map, in the inner while loop, why?

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler, and **mind the warnings**!

Comment: Compiler warnings aren't much help with this problem - I get no useful warnings from GCC with `-Wall -Wextra` or from MSVC with `-Wall -W4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send &map to the function, change the prototype to receive (int **map) or, use (*map)[i][k]. This is because indirection operator * has lower precedence than [] operator.

Comment: You might want to add a sentence or two about why `*map[i][k]` causes the crash.

Comment: Additionally, even after fixing the `map` access expression, the program is still prone to crashing if the input has lines that are too long.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect to end your while loop, did you ever kept a "\n" im your array? You have just allocated memory and trying to travel over it. It never finds an "\n" , thus while loop goes out the memory location and you get the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would use gdb or another debugger. Compile the program with debug symbols, run it in there, and it will tell you the line on which you're segfaulting.

Answer (score 0):

First -- heed advice given by 'prmg' and 'perreal'.

Do not cast the return value of malloc.  malloc returns a void * and the cast is unncessary.  Should you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`, you are setting yourself up for trouble.

```
map = malloc( height * sizeof *map );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your segmentation fault is coming from the fact that you're dereferencing `map` incorrectly; you should write it as `(*map)[i][k]` instead of `*map[i][k]`.  Although it's better to leave off the `&` in the call to `fill_map` and adjust the  prototype accordingly:

```
fill_map(map, height, width);
...
void fill_map(int **map, int height, int width)
{
  ...
  map[i][k] = character;
  ...
}
```

You can clean up your `malloc` calls like so:

```
map = malloc(height * sizeof *map);
```

and

```
map[i] = malloc(width * sizeof *map[i]);
```

The casts aren't necessary in C<sup>1</sup>, and are considered bad practice.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is *not* true in C++; a cast is required, but if you're writing C++ you should be using `new` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

What your are using is not a 2D array but just a simulation of it. In modern C, starting with C99, with "variably modified types" your task is as simple as this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void fill_map(size_t height, size_t width, char map[height][width]) {
  int character;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < width; k++) {
      if ((character = getchar()) != '\n')
        map[i][k] = character;
      else break;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  size_t height = 4, width = 6;
  char (*map)[width] = malloc(sizeof(char[height][width]));
  fill_map(height, width, map);
}
```

- pass the matrix dimensions first, then you can simply use them in the declaration of the matrix parameter
- use `size_t` for indexing
- don't cast the return of malloc
- be careful with the bounds of your loop
- also better check end of file (homework)